# How can i determine that the parameter of RestApi is required?

Tags: java, web-services, rest

How can i make the id parameter required?

```
@Get
@Path("/test")    
public class test{

   @Path("/test-method")
   public Response(@QueryParam String id){
    ..
    ..
   }
  }
```

Comment: What `@Required` annotation is this? What library are you using?

Comment: It is for spring library

Comment: There are so many Spring projects, you should be more specific. Like, do you mean [this `@Required`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html)? But there's no `@Get` annotation, so I still don't know for sure what you are talking about.

Comment: How can i determine that the input parameter of my  Rest Api is required?

Comment: I have asked several times for information; your latest response is a question that provides no information. I'm done here.

Comment: I am sorry, Thank you.